# Need different headers for each column on suggestion list for ng-autocomplete

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I am trying to bind ng-autocomplete with dynamic data(from database) through a array of object. I have multiple columns on suggestion list and I want different headers for each column on suggestion list.

I am trying to bind ng-autocomplete with dynamic data(from database) through an array of object. I have multiple columns on suggestion list and I want different headers for each column on suggestion list.

My HTML code:

```
<ng-autocomplete #auto
            [data]="data$ | async"
            [searchKeyword]="key" 
            [(ngModel)]="searchKey"
            (inputChanged)='getData($event)' 
            (inputFocused)='focused()' 
            [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" 
            autocomplete="off"
            [heading] ="header"
            (keydown.enter)="showDetails()"
            (inputCleared)="searchCleared()"
            [notFoundTemplate]="noTemplate" 
            [debounceTime]="300" 
            (closed)  ="closed()"
            placeholder= "enter text"
            [isLoading]="isLoadingResult" 
            [minQueryLength]="6"
            [customFilter]="customFilter"
        >
</ng-autocomplete>

<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
      <a>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-9">
                <span  [innerHTML]="item.firstNName" ></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                  <span [innerHTML]="item.lastName"></span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </a>
 </ng-template>
```

I need two different headers for firstName and LastName.

Comment: would you be able to show your current code? and give us more details ?_

Comment: I have added html code.